# How to chain multiple operator[]

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a class that use the operator [] like

```
MyClass[x][y]
```

and it should return a value based on what I call in the function that is defined within the class. What I have so far is:

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass{
   public:
          // return one value of the matrix
     friend double operator[][] (const int x, const int y); 
   }
```

I don't even think my syntax for this is right, and how can I write this function in MyClass.cpp to define what value it should return?

Like is it:

```
MyClass::friend double operator[][] (const int x, const int y)
{
  // insert code here
}
```

Tried it but it keeps saying errors. I believe it is a mess up there...

Many thanks,

Comment: You can't declare a `operator[][]`. You need two classes overloading `operator[]`, to achieve this effect.

Comment: You can only overload existing operators, and C++ doesn't have a `[][]` operator.

Comment: You also have a problem with your usage of `friend`. Declaring a function `friend` like you do means that it's a non-member function, yet you try to define it as a member function using the `friend` keyword in a syntactically illegal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading `operator()` is definitely the cleanest approach.

However, remember that this is C++, and you can bend the syntax to your will :)

In particular, if you insist on wanting to  use `myclass[][]`, you can do so by declaring an "intermediate class", here's an example:

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acd5a4d6ce800890)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class MyClass {
public:

    using IndexType  = int;
    using ReturnType = double;

    // intermediate structure
    struct YClass {
        MyClass&  myclass;
        IndexType x;
        YClass (MyClass& c, IndexType x_) : myclass(c), x(x_) {}
        ReturnType operator[](IndexType y_) { return myclass.compute(x, y_); }
    };


    // return an intermediate structure on which you can use opearator[]
    YClass operator[](IndexType x) { return {*this, x}; }

    // actual computation, called by the last "intremediate" class
    ReturnType compute(IndexType x, IndexType y) {
        return x * y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myclass;

    cout << myclass[2][3] << endl;  // same as: cout << myclass.compute(2, 3) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks, but also do you have any alternatives that can be worth looking into?

Comment: Glad it helps! AFAIK, that _(i.e. returning a temporary object which returns another temporary, etc.)_ is how you would proceed for _"chaining"_ before performing a _"terminal"_ action (e.g. `compute()`). There are quite a few techniques for customizing the calling syntax: e.g. operator overloading, templates, user-defined literals, providing STL-friendly iterators etc. It all depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a proxy object for the row. This is a very simplified example just to get you going. I have not tried compiling it.

```
class Matrix {
   int data[4][4];

   class Row {
      Matrix* matrix;
      int row;

      int operator[](int index){
        return matrix->data[row][index]; // Probably you want to check the index is in range here.
      }

   }

   Row operator[](int row){
     Row which_row;
     which_row.matrix = this;
     which_row.row = row; // beware that if the user passes the row around it might point to invalid memory if Matrix is deleted.
     return which_row;
   }
}
```

You could also just return the row directly from `operator[]` and leave the second `[]` to be a direct array access. IMHO it is nice with the proxy object as it can do some checking on the index and possibly have other nice member functions.

Comment: I am trying to compute a method that preferably does not involve storing any form of matrices to allow large scale problems though...

Comment: @QuangThinhHa You mean the data is not stored in the Matrix class itself? It only stores a reference/pointer to the data?

Comment: This method of chaining operator is just needed to double check my matrix-free algorithm, which will include a matrix inversion later on. So it is more like a stepping stone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `operator[][]`. But you can declare `operator()(int, int)` instead.

```
class Foo {
public:
  double operator()(int a, int b) {
    //...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create 4x4 Matrix class, the way I did it and the way its done in the D3DX library is to have a member variable in the class:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    // publicly accessible member 4x4 array
    float m[4][4];

    // also accessible via () operator. E.G. float value = mtx(3,2);
    float operator()(int column, int row);
}
```